# String operations that worked Xcode Beta 5 do not work in beta 6

Tags: xcode6

Simple operations like:

voiceName = voiceChar + voiceName

I get an error: Character is not convertible to UInt8
I was able to change this to voiceName = String(voiceChar) + voiceName
and it is Ok, but this was not necessary in Beta 5 and I cannot find this in the documentation

another error I get is:

voiceName = voice.substringFromIndex(index)
index is Int

I get an error: Int is not convertible to String.index

I deleted Derived Data from the project, but that did not help

Answer (score 0):

Since beta 6 you cannot append strings to characters. Because the "+" operator is only for concatenation. In [release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_6_gl2i5q/xcode_6__beta_6_release_notes.pdf) of xcode 6 beta 6 i found on page 9:

'String and Character have been revised to follow the changes to Array, which clarifies that 
the + operator is only for “concatenation", not “append”. Therefore String + Character, 
Character + String, and String += Character,as well as the analogous Array + Element
combinations, have been removed. You can still + two Characters or a String with any other 
sequence of Character or an Array with any other sequence of the same element type.'

The other error i have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found in an example in a book that `Character` was used instead of `String`.  By using `String` in place of `Character`, it resolved the error `Character is not convertible to UInt8`.

Comment: Give some snippet to improve your answer